# Implementing rewind function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, video

I have programmed a video player in Javascript and I am trying to implement a rewind / forward functionality.

The aim is that the video will rewind in when the button is held down. I programmed a version of this which would rewind once when the button is clicked but then you have to keep clicking it to rewind continuously.

So far I have done this:

HTML

```
<video id="media" width="600" height="400" preload="none">
    <source src="files/Best of 60s.m4v">
</video>    

<input type="button" id="skipTrackBackward" value="Backward" onmousedown="rewind()" onmouseup="stoprewind()"/>
```

Javascript:

```
    var skipB
    function initiate(){
    mmedia = document.getElementById('media');
    skipB = document.getElementById('skipTrackBackward');

function rewind(){
        while (!mmedia.paused && !mmedia.ended){
            for (var i = mmedia.currentTime; i != 0; i--){
                mmedia.currentTime=i;   
            }
        }   
    }

    function stoprewind(){
        mmedia.play();
    }
```

The above code causes my Chrome tab to crash so obviously I have done something very wrong! But my understanding is that I only want the rewind function to start provided the video has not reached its end or has been paused. So while it is in that state it should run the for loop which takes into account the currentTime which has elapsed and subtract 1 second while the mouse is pressed down (currentTime takes integers which are interpreted as seconds). It should keep updating currentTime as long as it has not reached 0 seconds.

The above code has been minimised for convenience. Any suggestion greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've created either an infinite loop *or* your setting `mmedia.currentTime` to a bogus value.

First lets cover trouble shooting. See what the console outputs, Add some `console.log` statements to see what the values are as it runs and what the values are just before it crashes, step through the code in the debugger (use conditional breakpoints to filter out the noise).

Now code analysis. Try replacing the variables with hard coded values and see if the logic pans out:

```
while (!mmedia.paused && !mmedia.ended) {
 ^1       ^2                  ^3
```

1. Why the while? is there a case where you need to run the for loop until `mmedia.paused` and `mmedia.ended`?
2. When does this variable change to break out of the loop?
3. Or this variable?

So when the for loop executes there is nothing to cause `mmedia.paused` or `mmedia.ended` to be changed from *false* to *true* and that is an infinite loop.

Also you check that `i != 0` is it possible for i to be `< 0`? And if so will `mmedia.currentTime` handle values less than 0?

Last but not least if you were to have a break out of the while / for loop it is in a blocking process. This means that if you rely on user interaction to flip one of the cancel flags it will never happen because the thread is waiting for the while / for loops to finish before registering that the user did something. If the infinite loop was fixed one click would prevent the pause / stop button from being clicked till it reached the beginning (obviously this is silly since you could just set `currentTime` to 0 in the first place). Another effect is that you won't see the rewind process because it won't update the display till the thread is finished executing code.

What you will need it to rewrite the logic in a non-blocking fashion. This is called asynchronous code and is a lot more complicated then a simple loop.

```
var stopRewinding;

function rewind() {
  var timeout = 100;
  stopRewinding = false;

  if (mmedia.paused || mmedia.ended) {
    console.log("Media state unable to rewind");
    return;
  }

  function worker() {
    if (stopRewinding || mmedia.currentTime <= 0) {
      return; // All done so get outa here
    }

    mmedia.currentTime--;

    setTimeout(worker, timeout);
  }

  worker();
}
```

Now you can interrupt the loop by setting `stopRewinding` to *true* or when the `currentTime` reaches 0.

You can then either have a button or use the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events to trigger `rewind()` and `stopRewinding = true`.

Comment: Hi Sukima, Thank so much for your detailed explanation. I now understand where I was going wrong. Using this knowledge I have been able to implement the forward function as well. Many thanks.